# 95% Confidence Bands Around Normal Plot?

Tags: plotting

How would one generate 95% confidence bands about a normal plot [as seen in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929611/recreate-minitab-normal-probability-plot) using Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: Greatly appreciated, but how would one construct a ProbabilityPlot of a data set with the confidence bands as shown above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pts = {
   {29, 22}, {31, 29}, {33, 36}, {33, 44},
   {35, 46}, {37, 49}, {39, 47}, {40, 52},
   {40, 61}, {43, 65}, {43, 71}, {44, 81}};

lm = LinearModelFit[Sort@pts, {1, x }, x];

{bands68[x_], bands95[x_], bands99[x_]} = Table[
   lm["SinglePredictionBands",
    ConfidenceLevel -> cl], {cl, {0.6827, 0.9545, 0.9973}}];
Show[ListPlot[Sort@pts],
 Plot[{lm[x], bands68[x], bands95[x], bands99[x]},
  {x, 0, 50}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}}],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 100}},
 ImageSize -> 480, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Many, many thanks.